# How to get Form Field Value Sitecore 9.0.1

Tags: sitecore-forms

I am using Sitecore 9 forms and I have created a custom save action and my requirement is I need to get Form feed value in my `CustomSaveAction` class which inherits `SubmitActionBase` class.

I am able to see the data in `formSubmitContext` object but not able to retrieve the data.

Can you please help me?

Thanks in advanced.

Comment: Crosspost:  see also https://community.sitecore.net/developers/f/10/t/10239

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find an example here: https://ggullentops.blogspot.com/2017/10/sitecore-9-forms-custom-submit-action.html

E.g. to get the value from a field called "Email":

```
var postedFormData = formSubmitContext.PostedFormData;
var field = postedFormData.Fields.FirstOrDefault(f => f.Name.Equals("Email"));
if (field != null)
{
    var property = field.GetType().GetProperty("Value");
    var postedEmail = property.GetValue(field);
    email= postedEmail.ToStringOrEmpty();
}
```

Not sure if this is still the best way to do it, but that used to work.

Seen some more recent code, and apparently what is done now is:

```
var email = GetValue(formSubmitContext.Fields.FirstOrDefault(f => f.Name.Equals("Email"));
```

GetValue function:

```
private string GetValue(object field)
{
  return field?.GetType().GetProperty("Value")?.GetValue(field, null)?.ToString() ?? string.Empty;
}
```

Comment: I am not getting how you got PostedFormData in SubmitAction?

Comment: Adapted answer.. snippet from more recent code. PostedFormData might have disappeared - I should check that.

Comment: You can use formSubmitContext.Fields instead of formSubmitContext.PostedFormData.Fields.

Comment: Hi Jan, thanks for help...i did the same what you suggested and i am getting the result.